# Bleeding gums on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, food, medicine

If someone has gum disease and his gums frequently (or always) bleed when he eats, is he restricted to a liquid diet on Shabbos and Yom Tov?

Comment: some sources, perhaps. http://www.torah.org/advanced/weekly-halacha/5761/kedoshim.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The recently-published sefer Orchos Shabbos suggests that one whould be allowed to eat in this situation, based on Dagul MeRevavah (quoted by Mishnah Berurah 340:17, concerning the consumption of food with words written on it) who rules that a *psik reishah d'lo nicha lei* (unwanted consequential act) is allowed in a case where the result is damaging (*m'kalkel*) and the act is done in an unusual manner (*k'lachar yad*). He cites Rav Nissim Karelitz shlit"a as being lenient regarding this issue.

Comment: It sounds like the basis is a derabanan with tarti l'rei'usa.  How does it play out in this case where mekalkel is chayav?  Now that you mention a psik reisha d'lo nicha lei, it should be very easy to permit this case since many poskim hold that that is mutar straightaway.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it's a shvus (doesn't want it) d'shvus (netilas neshama isn't done with food) bemakom tzaar or mitzva.  Although I don't know if that's the case when he's in pain/not oneg anyway.

There's probably a better answer.

Comment: "Netilas neshama isn't done with food" - why does that make it a shvus?

Comment: It's the equivelent of your k'lacher yad.  It make the melacha a derabanan.

Comment: What you said is pretty close to what I found in Orchos Shabbos, except that his logic seems to apply even where there is no tzaar or mitzvah (due to the element of m'kalkel?).